# Holo Dark TabWidget style for Holo Light Theme

Tags: android, tabwidget

I've got a custom theme that inherits from Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar and I'm trying to change the theme's tabWidget style so it to look like if the theme was Theme.Holo Dark.

I've tried this in my theme with no result

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
  <item name="android:tabWidgetStyle">@android:style/Widget.Holo.TabWidget</item>
...
</style>
```

The only thing I can appreciate is there is a small change in the blue bar of the tab.

Any idea how to get it? Thanks!

Comment: on which Android Version are you? API Level <14?

Comment: 8 and above. However, I use two styles (pre and post Honeycomb). I was trying this for API Level >= 11.

Comment: @Wakka I was also facing the same prm. How did you fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Try also the items `"android:tabStripLeft"` and `"android:tabStripRight"`.